# Postgresql does not prompt for password

Tags: postgresql, authentication

I have a postgresql 8.3 db set up on linux box, together with a user postgres
The pg_hba.conf reads

```
local   all         postgres                          ident sameuser
local   all         all                               md5
```

so no trusted connections from local machine.

Yet when connecting via commandline with psql, no password is asked and all users get all access to all databases.

I'm completely lost here..

Comment: Do you have any environment variables beginning with PG set? (E.g. PGUSER, PGHOST etc.)

Comment: @j_random_hacker The `~/.pgpass` file was the issue in my case, thanks! Didn't even know it exists. It contained the password in clear text, too... I deleted it and now PostgreSQL asks for password, as expected.

Comment: Glad to hear it @CamilB :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Are you sure you did restart or reload of PostgreSQL after pg_hba.conf change?

If yes, type this command from postgres system account (shell):

```
psql -qAt -c "show hba_file" | xargs grep -v -E '^[[:space:]]*#'
```

If this will not help - show us output of the command.

Comment: Turns out that I was looking at the wrong conf file due to a wierd mixup. Found out thanks to the show hba_file (didnt know about the command  before)

Comment: I am recreating a postgresql configuration, and this command helped me compare the new configuration with the old one. +1 and starred question for that.

Answer (score 5):

You have to change both lines for IPv4 and IPv6 in pg_hba.conf

```
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all         all         127.0.0.1/32          md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all         all         ::1/128               md5
```

Server restart is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 host   all   all   127.0.0.1/32        md5
```

instead.