# How to Force Postgresql User Login with Password

Tags: postgresql, authentication, passwords

All I did is in my **local** machine(Mac OS).
After installing the postgresql, I created a user named poet with password, then created a database named poems and the database's owner is poet.
What I am curious is that I can log into poems with poet without password.
The command is `psql -U poet -d poems`.
Then what's the usage of the password?
I know that I can add -W to get the password prompt `psql -U poet -d poems -W`, but I can still log in even with a wrong password!
Then I modify the config file(/usr/local/var/postgres/pg_hba.conf) like below:

```js
# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
#local   all             all                                     trust
local   all             all                                     password
# IPv4 local connections:
#host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            password
# IPv6 local connections:
#host    all             all             ::1/128                 trust
host    all             all             ::1/128                 password
```

And restart the server, I still don't need to provide the password to log into the database.

Can someone tell how to force the server to verify the correctness of login password?

Comment: FYI: If you use `METHOD` as `password`  it will be sent in clear text. Instead try using `crypt`, `md5` or something more secure. BTW are you sure the password is there in  `pg_shadow` system table?

Comment: @MarlonAbeykoon, Thanks for your advice. I can find the poet in the table pg_shadow and also his password is encrypted.

Comment: Maybe you find useful this answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/11956126/1579961

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Postgresql does not prompt for password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1335503/postgresql-does-not-prompt-for-password)

Answer (score 12):

This was happening to me as well. Non privileged accounts were able to login with invalid passwords. The steps I took to resolve it were.

Find the right pg_hba.conf file.

```
$ psql -h 127.0.0.1 -U admin -W postgres
Password for user admin: 
psql (9.6.5)
Type "help" for help.

openproject_dev=# SHOW hba_file ;
              hba_file               
-------------------------------------
 /usr/local/var/postgres/pg_hba.conf
(1 row)
```

Edit the file to force password login ... Leave admin (superuser) as trust.
I used md5 instead of password .. password worked as well.

```
# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             admin                                   trust
local   all             all                                     md5
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             admin           127.0.0.1/32            trust
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             admin           ::1/128                 trust
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
```

Save pg_hba.conf file and restart the postgres server.

Comment: Is it possible to script all of this? This is insane. I'd like to be able to create a user with a password automatically and not have to worry about editing the damn file. :(.

Comment: It's an edge case. I've only had to do this once with all the postgres installs I've done and yes ... it could be scripted.

Comment: Yes. I was able to script it using `HBA_FILE=$(cd /tmp && sudo -u postgres psql -qAt -F '|' -c "SELECT current_setting('hba_file')")` and then `sudo sed -i "s/host.*all.*all.*127.0.0.1\/32.*ident/host all all 127.0.0.1\/32 md5/" ${HBA_FILE}
sudo sed -i "s/host.*all.*all.*::1\/128.*ident/host all all ::1\/128 md5/" ${HBA_FILE}`

Comment: Impressive :-) Cheers!

Comment: This did not solve my issue. I can run `psql -U <username> <dbname>` without a password and still log in

Comment: Did you reboot the server after changing the pg_hba.conf
 file?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it will work for you to create the database's user and schema in PostgreSQL:

1. Log into PostgreSQL from the `postgres` user

```
$ sudo -u postgres psql postgres
```

2. Once in, create the user and database

```
CREATE ROLE myuser LOGIN PASSWORD 'mypass';
CREATE DATABASE mydatabase WITH OWNER = myuser;
```

3. Log into PostgreSQL from the new user account

```
$ psql -h localhost -d mydatabase -U myuser -p <port>
```