# How to force using password

Tags: postgresql

I have just installed PostgreSQL on my Mac After the installation I logged in via:

`$ psql postgres`

At the next step I created new database:

`CREATE DATABASE sample_db;`

And now I added a user and grant it access to created DB:

`CREATE USER sample_user WITH PASSWORD 'sample_pass';`

`GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE sample_db TO sample_user;`

When I log in with user, I do not need to enter the password:

`psql sample_db -U sample_user`

even, if I provide the `-W` option.

Also, if I try to log in with this user via some SQL-GUI such a tableplus.

How can I configure postgresql to force user using their password?

I modified the `pg_hba.conf` file to looking like this:

```
host sample_db sample_user 127.0.0.1/32 password
```

My intention or my guess was that psql will use it. But somehow it doesn't.

I also checked [How to Force Postgresql User Login with Password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29679507/how-to-force-postgresql-user-login-with-password), but with no positive effect to my issue.

pg_hba.conf

```
local all admin trust
local all all md5
host all admin 127.0.0.1/32 trust
host all all 127.0.0.1/32 md5
host all admin ::1/128 trust
host all all ::1/128 md5
```

Comment: Because `psql sample_db -U sample_user` is using a local socket not TCP and I'm betting you have a line in `pg_hba.conf` that start with `local` and allows `trust`. See [pg_hba.conf](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auth-pg-hba-conf.html).

Comment: I added. Also some lines more for blocking all other users except the admin. No effect. :-/

Comment: Added what? Did you have the server reload it's conf files? Add the contents of your `pg_hba.conf` as text to question.

Comment: I repeat, "Add the contents of your pg_hba.conf as text to question."

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I added it as text

Comment: 1) Did you have the server reload or restart? 2) What is the complete `psql` command you are using to connect?

Comment: I added a solution down below for this problem. Thank you Adrian, for your support!

Answer (score 0):

**I have a solution**

The thing is that while you installing postgresql via brew there will be two pathes, where pg_hba.conf can potentially exist.

**Wrong path:** /opt/homebrew/opt/postgresql@15/share/postgresql@15/pg_hba.conf
[Screen: inactive pg_hba path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kAMqJ.png)

**Right path:** /opt/homebrew/var/postgresql@15/pg_hba.conf
[Screen: active pg_hba path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5lCRs.png)

---

You can find the path of your pg_hba.conf inside **pg_settings** table. Just run

```
select * from pg_settings;
-
select setting from pg_settings where name = 'hba_file';
```

---

After placement of needed configuration and postgresql server restart, everything works like expected.